# Function does not recognize typedef argument

Tags: c, function, struct, typedef, argument-passing

okay, ive searched a solution for like two days now but i couldnt find whats going wrong with my code. ;(

The task is simple: define a new type using typedef and have a function read out lines of this new type from a file into an array of again this new type. so my typedef inside the headerfile looks like this right now (ive tried several variants of writing this)

```
// filename: entries.h
#ifndef ENTRIES_H_
#define ENTRIES_H_
#include<time.h>

typedef struct{
    char Loginname[25];
    time_t RegDate;
    unsigned long Highscore;
    time_t Hdate;
}typePlayerEntry;

int readPlayerList(char *name, typePlayerEntry *feld);

#endif /* ENTRIES_H_ */
```

the main.c:

```
//filename: main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include "entries.h"


int main(void) {
    char name[13]="numbers.txt";
    typePlayerEntry *pep;

    readPlayerList(name, pep);

    return 0;
}
```

my function file looks like this (and heres where the error is shown)

```
//filename: readPlayerList.c

int readPlayerList(char *name, typePlayerEntry *feld) {
return 0;
}
```

irrelevant code is completely left out. The problem is reproducable with the code posted.

the program wont compile because the type of the second argument in the function file could not be recognized,
- which is odd, because its defined in the header file and also usable in the main function.
And this error is somehow connected to the declaration of (in this case) a pointer of type playerEntry in my main.c. So if i do not declare it, theres no error, though i have to declare it to actually give it to the function. how come that the solution so far is to include the entries.h into the readPlayerList.c, which wasnt neccesary for previous functions?

im using eclipse kepler with MinGW, in case thats a compiler issue.

corrected the missing include of time.h and adjusted the code a little.

Comment: Looks right to me. Are the struct and typedef declarations both in front of the function declaration?

Comment: Ok you've stated that these appears in the header file... but did you include it in the source where it's used?

Comment: @nneonneo yes, edited my question showing the entire files used that produce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `#include <time.h>` in entries.h.

```
// filename: entries.h
#ifndef ENTRIES_H_
#define ENTRIES_H_

typedef struct {
    char Loginname[25];
    time_t RegDate;                  /* from <time.h> */
    unsigned long Highscore;
    time_t Hdate;                    /* from <time.h> */
} playerEntry;

int readPlayerList(char *name, playerEntry *feld);

#endif /* ENTRIES_H_ */
```

And you need to `#include "entries.h"` in readPlayerList.c

```
//filename: readPlayerList.c

int readPlayerList(char *name, typePlayerEntry *feld) {
/*                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ from entries.h */
return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes, that solves the problem! thank you. however can you explain why it is that way? i never had to include anything in my function.c's and really believed it all comes with the main.c includes. why isnt that the case here?

Comment: The .c files are basically different "translation units". Each one stands on its own and they are only 'merged' in the last process of creating an executable: the linking state. Before that, each one is compiled separately (your compiler hides that for ease of use) and each one must use the correct includes.

Answer (score 0):

part of the problem is the compiler is seeing (at least) two different meanings/definitions for the 'playerEntry' name.

Suggest:
1) eliminate the 'typedef' statement 
(it is just cluttering the code and confusing the compiler)

2) properly reference the struct via:
 'struct playerEntry' instead of 'playerEntry'

in TheHeader.h file:

```
struct playerEntry
{
    char Loginname[25];
    time_t RegDate;
    unsigned long Highscore;
    time_t Hdate;
};

int readPlayerList(char *name, struct playerEntry *feld);
```

in the source file:

```
#include "TheHeader.h"
int readPlayerList(char *name, struct playerEntry *feld)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP's question said *"The task is simple: define a new type using typedef"*.

Comment: when i try your solution, its spitting with another error on me and treats the second argument "struct playerEntry *feld" as a struct creation within a function call, well at least thats how i interpret the warning... ill edit my post and put in there the full files im using which create this behaviour